# How do i put HTML code into PHP for visual composer addon development?

Tags: php, html, wpbakery

I have tried to ammend the code the best i can but i am a beginner, any help would be appreciated.

When launching my code i get fatal error.

This output works

```
public function renderMyBartag( $atts, $content = null ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'foo' => 'something',
    'color' => '#FF0000'
  ), $atts ) );
  $content = wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content, true); // fix unclosed/unwanted paragraph tags in $content

  $output = "<div style='color:{$color};' data-foo='${foo}'>{$content}</div>";
  return $output;
}
```

This does not

```
public function renderMyBartag( $atts, $content = null ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'foo' => 'something',
    'color' => '#FF0000'
  ), $atts ) );
  $content = wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content, true); // fix unclosed/unwanted paragraph tags in $content

  $output = "<div class="container">
    < class="learn-more">
        <div class="circle">
            <span class="icon arrow"></span>
            </div>
    <p class="button-text">{$foo}</p>
     </button>
    </div>"
;
  return $output;
}
```

When launching my code i get fatal error.

i just want to embed the html code into the shortcode i am creating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your $output, replace the the inner double quotes with single quotes or escape the double quotes.

```
<?php
    $o = " 'single quoute' ";
    $o_esc = " \"escaped_doublequotes\" ";
```